# apache proxy regex

Tags: apache, proxy

I have a setting for apache proxy not work but I don't know where is wrong...

I set apache proxy setting in XAMPP.

```
Alias /admin "my folder"
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPassMatch "/admin(.*)" !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8787/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8787/
```

I want the url with **/admin** stop proxy and go to alias folder.

the url `http:://localhost/admin/` works well.

But `http://localhost/admin/index` doesn't...

Who can tell me where is wrong...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried 
```ProxyPassMatch "\/admin(.*)" !```
, but it doesn't work...

Comment: also tried ```ProxyPassMatch "\/admin\/?(?:[^\/]+\/?)*" !```